# unable to take instanceof of a class when it has a $inject property (Typescript, Angular 1)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to use Typescript Type Guards, e.g.,

```
if ( x instanceof class) {
    //do thing;
}
```

I have a class that gives this error when I try to do an instanceof on it:
`The right-hand side of an instanceof expression must be of type 'any' or of a type assignable to the 'Function' interface type.`

My class has a `static $inject: Array<any> = ['dependencies'];` property to work with Angular 1.  When I remove this property (or even just rename it to `inject` (without the $ sign) I am able to do an instanceof.

Can anyone shed some light on this problem?

**Edit:** Relevant code:

Controller:

```
export class Controller {
    static $inject: Array<any> = ['$q', '$timeout'];

    constructor (private $q, private $timeout) {...}
}
```

Class:

```
class Selector {

    constructor(private ctrl: Controller | Controller1) {
        if(ctrl instanceof Controller) { 
            // This instanceof throws the aforementioned error
            // Renaming $static to static in Controller fixes the problem, 
            // but then the controller doesn't function
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: can you post the code for the class/controller?

Comment: Posted relevant code

Comment: I don't know why compiler raises this error, but to fix it just change `$inject` type to `Array<string>` or `string[]`.

Comment: Also it seems that this working fine in typescript 2, so maybe it is bug in previous version.

Comment: It's Array<any> so I can run `Controller.$inject.concat(Controller)` to register it with angular elsewhere, rather than have magic strings running amuck.
And is that so?  I'll have to look into that.